# Cannot generate adhoc IPA from command-line but it works in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line, archive, ipa

I'm trying to generate an adhoc IPA from the command-line but I cannot get it to works.

I can however generate an adhoc IPA from Xcode doing `Product -> Archive` and `Export...` in Organizer.

Here is how I proceed to generate an IPA on the command-line

```
xcodebuild -project DemoApp.xcodeproj -scheme DemoApp archive -archivePath build/DemoApp.xcarchive -configuration Release

xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v build/DemoApp.xcarchive/Products/Applications/DemoApp.app -o build/DemoApp.ipa --sign "iPhone Distribution" --embed DemoApp_Adhoc.mobileprovision
```

When I install the generated IPA via iTunes, it doesn't install properly on the device. The icon is greyed out and the title says "Installing..." like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20672448/app-stuck-on-installing-ipa-from-itunes).

I've checked the provisioning profile, the UUID, etc.

I tried with [shenzhen](https://github.com/nomad/shenzhen) but got the same behavior.

Can you spot what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I did not find the problem with `PackageApplication` but as a workaround I used `PROVISIONING_PROFILE` and `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY` environment variable with the `xcodebuild` step and it worked.

Here are the new commands:

```
xcodebuild -project DemoApp.xcodeproj -scheme DemoApp archive -archivePath build/DemoApp.xcarchive -configuration Release PROVISIONING_PROFILE="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution: Company Inc (XXXXXXXXXX)"

xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v build/DemoApp.xcarchive/Products/Applications/DemoApp.app -o build/DemoApp.ipa")
```