# iOS app installed failed thru iTunes

Tags: ios, installation, itunes, ipa, failed-installation

I am trying install an iOS app into iPhone. I build that app using enterprise license and build the IPA. Then I tried to install into iPhone using iTunes, it worked fine in one of my device (iOS version 9.2.1).

But when I tried to install it in another device, it not installing. What I did was dragged to iPA into iTunes and click on install and apply button (I did the same for my other device). But what happens is, the intermediate install icon appears and that install animation is coming. But after that it disappears. No error message is displaying. Any help on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***4 Ways/Methods to install ipa file (app) on iPhone / iPad / iPod Online + offline methods***

**Method # 1 – Using iTunes.**

iTunes too provides a functionality to directly install ipa apps on your device. Perform the following steps to install ipa apps through iTunes –

Connect your Phone to computer and launch iTunes.
Drag the app’s .ipa file into iTunes library.
Click on Sync and done, that’s it . If the app was earlier backed up from the same device, it would be installed without any fuss.

**Method # 2 – iFunbox**

iFunbox is yet another easy method to install ipa files/apps on your iPhone. Perform the following steps to install Apps on your iPad/iPhone through ifunbox –

Download and install ifunbox from [i-funbox.com](http://www.i-funbox.com) if not already installed.
Launch iFunbox and connect your iPhone/iPad/iPod.
Now navigate to the File Browser tab as shown in the figure and select “*User Applications*” (Highlighted in the same figure).
Now click on “*Install App*” button, select the ipa or apmx file of app which you want to install and click on Open!
Yo! The app will be installed successfully.

**Method # 3 Online Method : Diawi**

Diawi is a tool for iOS developers to deploy Development and Ad hoc iOS applications or install them directly to the device. Here are the steps to follow to install apps through Diawi –

1. Open [Diawi.com](http://diawi.com/) .
2. Upload the application and its provisioning profile.
3. Send the link to your testers, clients, friends or even use it yourself. (Either by Mail , WhatsApp etc)
4. Open the link in Safari on the iOS device and click on install.

**Method # 4 – iTools**

As we’ve mentioned earlier that iTools is probably the best alternative to iTunes, and the tutorial to install apps on iPhone is very similar to the one we used for backing-up /extract ipa files of iPhone/iPod apps.

Connect your phone to computer and launch iTools , You can download iTools from the following links –

[Click here to download iTools for Windows 7/8/8.1/10.](http://itools.en.uptodown.com/download)

[Click here to download iTools for Mac OS.](http://dl2.itools.hk/dl/iTools_2.4.4.dmg)

After connecting your phone & launching iTools go to  the “Applications” tab on the left hand side.
Now, click on the “Install” button.
Select the ipa file which you want to install, and click on Open.
That’s it your app will be installed successfully!
So, these are some of the methods which i used to deploy/install ipa apps on my iPhone/iPod .If you encounter any problems or know of another such method feel free to comment

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried method#1. Then I am getting the issue. The app is built using enterprise provisioning. Is the issue related with certificates?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20672448/app-stuck-on-installing-ipa-from-itunes
Have a look?

Comment: You can also use ideviceinstaller on linux runs really well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see the device log from Xcode when installing, I think it's due to lack of enterprise provision cert on the new device?